# Magento 2.3 - Storefront and Admin urls at localhost:8081 show 404 / not found

Tags: magento2

After successfully installing Magento (environment below), url's to access storefront and admin show a 404/Not Found errors. What am i missing?

Environment:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.2
- Apache 2.4.37
- PHP 7.2.9
- MySQL 8.0

While installing:

1. Apache is running on port `8081`
2. I chose the store name to be `magento` instead of `magento2`

Tried these:

1. Copied `.htaccess` from `/htdocs/magento2/app/pub` to `/htdocs/magento2/`
2. Updated `httpd.conf` file to `Listen 8081` , `ServerName localhost:8081` and enabled `LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so`

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You said you copied files to  /htdocs/magento2 in error is magento directory, without number 2

Comment: No, it is correct the full path for my `magento2` directory is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2`. While installing i chose the store name to be `magento` instead of the default `magento2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a pretty similar issue, just on a windows machine instead. Here is another step you can try to see if it helps. So go to pub/static folder and delete everything except htaccess. Then open up app/etc/di.xml find the path “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” and replace to “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy”. Then clear cache and maybe restart apache and try again? 
I got this from http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/ which is windows specific, but I don't think that this issue is windows specific.

Comment: Thanks. Tried all of them now.. but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing Magento with the below change, the URL's were working.
I tried While installing.

- At 3rd step : Web Configuration, while entering "Your Store Address", replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` and you can still use custom port. After install you will see the URLs to Storefront and Admin (as below).

[image]

- `http://127.0.0.1:8081/magento2/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8081/magento2/admin_2lecxk/` should load without errors.

[image]

Note: I'm still not sure what fixed or how this works. I have raised a GitHub issue [#20355](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20355) for Magento team to look.

Comment: You change directory to correct in installation like I was writing  to magento2 , compare your screens